# Editable vimgrep string in command line

Tags: vim

I use vimgrep a lot to navigate in files and usually use the last search from the history to modify the search pattern and run it again.

Is there a way to display in the command line an **editable** string like the one below, with the cursor already positioned between the two search pattern slashes (and the pattern being empty)?

`:vimgrep // **/*[ch]|copen`

I don't want to use a constant mapping (like the one at [this vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim)) since I want to be able to add/change options (\c etc.).

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using the command-line window for this (`q:` opens it from normal mode), since you
can edit the command with the regular normal mode keystrokes (and you get syntax highlighting too).

You can also move around in your history just like in a normal buffer. So `?vimgrep<Enter>nnn`... will search for and move you to all your old `vimgrep` commands.

Just hit `<Enter>` as normal when you are done editing, or `:q<Enter>` to abort the command and quit the window like you would any other.

Finally, here's a mapping to quickly bring up your empty `vimgrep` template in the command-line window.

```
:nnoremap \v q:ivimgrep<Space>//<Space>**/*[ch]<Bar>copen<Esc>F/;i
```

*Reference:* `:help cmdline-window`