# vimscript: Generate an editable command from vimscript/mapping

Tags: vim

I started with a mapping from [this vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim) to use `lvimgrep` to search across files for the current word under cursor:

```
map <F4> :execute "lvimgrep /" . expand("<cword>") . "/j **" <Bar> lw<CR>
```

I realized that I'd like to edit the file glob path or search pattern before the command's actually executed.
for ex: when cursor is on a javascript variable in html file, pressing `F4` just searches for the variables in the html files. It'd be better if it formed command and let me edit it before its executed.
Dropping the trailing `<CR>` prints out the code as is - command window shows:

```
 :execute "lvimgrep /" . expand("<cword>") . "/j **" <Bar> lw
```

but that's hard to edit. I'd actually like the mapping to show:

```
 :lvimgrep /theword/j *.js //---- cursor waiting here
```

I've tried all that I could but not sure how to go about it - and vimscript's not exactly easy.

**PS: possible dupe of [Editable vimgrep string in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535424/editable-vimgrep-string-in-command-line)**

**PPS**: final mapping (I've used `<leader>*`):

```
  nnoremap <expr> <leader>* ":lvimgrep /" . expand("<cword>") . "/j **/*." .  expand("%:e") . "\|lopen"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a `:help map-expr` instead of `:execute`. This evaluates the expression *and then* uses the result as the right-hand side of the mapping:

```
:nnoremap <expr> <F4> ":lvimgrep /" . expand("<cword>") . "/j **"
```

Alternatively, you could insert the current word with `<C-r><C-w>`:

```
:nnoremap <F4> :lvimgrep /<C-r><C-w>/j **
```

Additional tip: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: perfect - the `<expr>` mapping worked beautifully